# SSL and TLS protocols in IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, tls1.2

Is it possible if i only enabled TLS 1.2 in the IIS Application?

[image: ![iis]

It keeps showing the below errors when i applied only TLS 1.2.

[image]

If there are TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, the IIS application did work. but the properties shown are TLS 1.0 and not TLS 1.2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the TLS handshake the server will choose the best protocol supported by the client. Given that the connection only results in TLS 1.0 if your client is connecting to a server which support TLS 1.0...TLS 1.2 it looks like your (unknown) client only supports TLS 1.0. In this case it is no surprise that it will fail if the server has only TLS 1.2 enabled.

Comment: My project framework shows the properties as a 3.5 framework, but the IIS framework used is 2.0.  Is there any way i can let the application run in TLS 1.2?

Comment: @whoami: You original question asks about TLS 1.2 only in IIS and this question has been answered. In your comment you are asking about enabling TLS 1.2 on the client side within a specific framework, i.e. a completely new question. Please don't ask new questions inside a comment, instead create a new question with enough detail to answer it: this way others will see it too and can provide you valuable answers or will find answers if they face the same problem as described in the question (and not in some comment where nobody expects this).